# ng-show directive not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using ng-show directive to show/hide the alert box in my ui:

`<alert ng-show="{{showAlert()}}">{{showAlert()}}</alert>`

My controller code is:

`$scope.showAlert = function () {
    return userForm.$invalid || false;
  };`

Though I am getting correct value for the content of the alert and I am able to see the booelan values in the ui but the alert still keeps on showing.

Any idea?

Comment: Try `ng-show="showAlert()"`?

Comment: tried! but its not working too!

Comment: I think this is associated with the `alert` directive of the angular-ui only because I can't reproduce the same error for the normal span fields.

Comment: Could you create a reduced test case on http://jsfiddle.net? Someone might be able to help you better that way.

Comment: @Dogbert, here's an [example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AgdBWdux943BaIwjGScX) based on the [Angular UI _alert_](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert).  In the Plunker the alerts will not show.  Remove the _ng-show_ (line 13 in the HTML) and the alerts appear.  Is it possible to get _ng-show_ to work with Angular UI's _alert_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ng-show` accepts an expression.
2. `userForm` lives in the `$scope`.

template:

```
<span ng-show="showAlert()">form is invalid!!</span>
```

controller:

```
$scope.showAlert = function() {
  return $scope.userForm.$invalid || false;
};
```

Or, simply:

```
<span ng-show="userForm.$invalid">form is invalid!!!</span>
```

and link to the working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/nlc1dbtk8VaZBBGJnlb0

Comment: No, it doesn't work either. Have you tried it? In fact when I see the html output then I can see `ng-show='userForm.$invalid'` which means it not evaluated.